# how to place a number in the center of a span tag

Tags: html, css

I have a span tag which has got rounded circle with  the height 30 px and widhth 30 px. 
I am setting some number to the span tag.

i would like the number should be placed to the center of the circle. but it is moving towards the top center.

i tried setting sytle: text-align:center.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This depends on how you create the circle. Please post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's too high, have you tried

```
line-height: 30px;
```

yet?

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete solution:

```
.yourSpanClass {
    displ
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope it helps